# Have specific CSS if a class is after another element with a particular ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this scenario:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="a"></div>
   <li class="b"></li>
</div>
```

In my case, I want to add margin-top: 5px; to class b only if it is after id a. Note that these are not children, but within the same element.

I would like an approach using pure CSS or CSS3 and without the need to use LESS or SASS. I know that this might be possible using JavaScript or jQuery as well, was just wondering if it can be done in CSS and how.

Comment: You're not supposed to have a li there. Perhaps you could just replace it with a div for the purposes of this example. And CSS and CSS3 are the same language, not two distinct ones, so it doesn't really make sense to say "CSS or CSS3".

Comment: here you find a list of cool css selectors also including the adjacent selector mentioned in the answer

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/08/10-css-selectors-you-shouldnt-code-without/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 - select element after another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992849/css3-select-element-after-another-element)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the **adjacent sibling selector**. Following will select all elements with class .b that follow element with id #a:

```
#a + .b {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Adjacent sibling selector is part of the CSS 2.1 spec and is supported in IE7+

Read more about CSS child and sibling selectors in here: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/76qJm/3/

Comment: This will also select class of "b" if it was before id "a" , which I don't think OP wanted

Comment: Your fiddle lost the first .b, here's an update that shows .b changing from blue to red (with #a being green): http://jsfiddle.net/76qJm/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target many elements with class b, then you need to use `~` selector. The selector `+` will find the next immediate element only. Update your CSS like below.

```
#a ~ .b {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
```